# What does this sentence "What a fool I was to do it!" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does this sentence mean?

> What a fool I was to do it!

I think it means either of them below according to context.

1.I was a fool that I was going to do it!

2.I was a fool that I did it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your recastings are not idiomatic

> What a fool I was to do it

is a very emphatic way to say

> I was a fool to do it

or

> I was foolish to do it

or

> It was foolish of me to do it.

All are simply admissions of having done something foolish.

Comment: Does that my recastings are not idiomatic mean they are also grammatically incorrect? I don't see what's wrong and have no ideas why you think of them as not idiomatic. I can find some similar sentences used by authors who seem to be native speakers.

Comment: @Floret Yes, it means they are grammatically inaccurate. There is also: I was such a fool to do it, which I am sure Jeff will agree with.

Comment: @Lambie actually, your revised version sounds way better than mine. But I still can't see anything wrong in them.

Comment: Or, “I was a fool *for* doing it.”

Answer (score -1):

The second one is correct in the past tense, the infinite phase does not affect the tense.

Present:

"What a fool I am to do it since I know he's lying."

Future:

"What a fool I'll be to do it if he continues to lie."

Comment: By the way, are my recastings grammatically incorrect? I don't see what's wrong.

Comment: No, they are grammatically correct, but your question was asking which tense was correct in describing "what a fool I was to do it".

Comment: But are they not idiomatic even to you?